# Sorting Array by an added variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

Adding a variable to the end of a mysql query.
Now I need to be able to sort by the associated value. Can someone help? I have tried several different sorting methods.

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($datacon,
    "SELECT * FROM spreadsheet 
        WHERE brand = '$brand' 
            AND package = '$package' 
            AND HIDE_FROM_SEARCH = '0' 
        GROUP BY ACCTNAME $pages->limit");

echo mysqli_error($datacon);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $lat_B=$row['LATITUDE'];
    $long_B=$row['LONGITUDE'];

    $lat_A = round($lat_A,2);
    $long_A = round($long_A,2);
    $lat_B = round($lat_B,2);
    $long_B = round($long_B,2);
    $distance = new calcDist($lat_A, $long_A, $lat_B, $long_B);
    $distance = $distance->calcDist($lat_A, $long_A, $lat_B, $long_B);
    $distance = round($distance,2);
    $locationSort=array($row);
    $locationSort['distance']=$distance;

    FOR EACH SOMETHING?
}
```

I have amended my previous post to reflect my usage of an answer.

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($datacon,"SELECT * FROM spreadsheet WHERE brand = '$brand'
                AND package = '$package' and HIDE_FROM_SEARCH = '0' GROUP BY ACCTNAME $pages->limit");

                echo(mysqli_error($datacon));
                class sortBydistance
                {
                    function sortBydistance($a, $b) {
                        if ($a['distance'] == $b['distance']) {
                            return 0;
                        }
                        return ($a['distance'] < $b['distance']) ? -1 : 1;
                    }
                }
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                {
                        $lat_B=$row['LATITUDE'];
                        $long_B=$row['LONGITUDE'];

                    $lat_A = round($lat_A,2);
                    $long_A = round($long_A,2);
                    $lat_B = round($lat_B,2);
                    $long_B = round($long_B,2);
                    $distance = new calcDist($lat_A, $long_A, $lat_B, $long_B);
                    $distance = $distance->calcDist($lat_A, $long_A, $lat_B, $long_B);
                    $distance = round($distance,2);


                }
                $locationSort=array($row);
                $locationSort['distance']=$distance;
                uasort($locationSort, array($this, "sortBydistance"));
                print_r($locationSort);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you wish to accomplish here. Can you expand on your question?

Comment: Basically I grab locations from a database and then calculate distance within the while loop. What I need to do now, is add the variable "distance" to the array. And then sort by distance within that array. I have been able to add the distance to the array, but I cannot get the array to sort by distance.

Comment: You can provide a sort callback to the function `usort` which will allow you to sort based on the value of distance.

Comment: I have tried but I don't understand how to specifically sort it by the distance variable.

Comment: Warning: asort() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given when I try this: asort($locationSort, 'distance');
                        print_r($locationSort);

Comment: it seems like you are overwriting your variables every time the while loop runs so that you only have the data of the last result of your query. do you have an array with the names and distances of the locations your getting?

Comment: Yes. I can print the array and show the distance within the while loop. I am trying to add the distance to the array, and then sort the results again from the new array.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not retrieving correctly the $bran and $package variables..

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($datacon,
    "SELECT * FROM spreadsheet 
        WHERE brand = '".$brand."' 
            AND package = '".$package."' 
            AND HIDE_FROM_SEARCH = '0' 
        GROUP BY ACCTNAME ".$pages->limit.");
```

Comment: The query works well, without calculating distance. My issue is that I am sorting by distance within the while loop. Ultimately I had to add the "distance" variable to the array. And Now I am having issues sorting the array... with the distance variable. When I print the array before sorting... the distance variable is there. But I don't understand how to sort... by the new variable.

Answer (score 0):

First, create your array of entries, and store it in an array, we will call `$rows`.

You want to use the PHP function `usort` here to provide a custom sorting callback.

Let's say you have an array like the following:

```
$rows = array(
    array("latitude" => 5, "distance" => 10),
    array("latitude" => 10, "distance" => 5),
    array("latitude" => 56, "distance" => 48)
);
```

You expect this array of `$rows` to be reordered so that the entry with `latitude == 10` is first, `latitude == 5` is second, and `latitude == 56` is third, based on their distance.

```
usort($rows, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = $a['distance'];
    $b = $b['distance'];

    return $a == $b ? 0 : $a > $b ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => 10
            [distance] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => 5
            [distance] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => 56
            [distance] => 48
        )

)
```

[See this demonstration at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/c11YH5)

---

Alternatively, you could try to find a SortedArray implementation that would keep the elements sorted as they were inserted to the array, rather than only when you call `usort()` on the array. That's a little too advanced for this question, though.

Comment: Does this instance work for complex arrays? My initial query spits out about 15-20 variables and distance ammends that array. I replaced my asort code with this example, and it removed the error, but doesn't seem to be sorting.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your array, by using `print_r($myArray);` so we can see its structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try this after your `while` loop:

```
uasort($locationSort, 'sortBydistance');
// or uasort($locationSort, array($this, "sortBydistance")); if you are using withing a class
print_r($locationSort);

function sortBydistance($a, $b) {
    if ($a['distance'] == $b['distance']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['distance'] < $b['distance']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear that he needs `uasort` as opposed to `usort` here. His original array isn't associative.

Comment: true, but it does not hurt to use an associative user sort either.

Comment: Well, it hurts from a performance standpoint, but it's a pretty negligible loss I believe, so I could agree there.

Comment: Warning: uasort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'sortBydistance' not found or invalid function name  then Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sortBydistance() (previously declared

Comment: @RevoTech That error should be fairly easy to figure out.

Comment: Maybe I just need to come back after a coffee break. I have been at this for 16 hours with no avail.

Comment: @RevoTech are you sure you are declaring function outside while. It works for me.

Comment: Outside as in before the while? I didn't think that would work, as my distance is calculated within, and then the variable added to the array, within.

Comment: while { creates array from data data/calculates distance - for each array variable sorted by distance } thats what I am trying to do.

Comment: No, after while. Also, If this is inside class, you have to use `uasort($locationSort, array($this, "sortBydistance"));` instead

Comment: in that case, you can call `uasort` inside while.

Comment: See the amended section of my previous post? I have altered the while loop to see if I am following what you are asking me to do?   (Thank you so much @dhavald)

Comment: You dont have to use class. Remove class wrapper but keep `sortBydistance` function as is and use `uasort($locationSort, 'sortBydistance');` and let us know if there is any error.